# pyodbc with MultiSubnetFailover

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, database-connection, pyodbc

Recently, one of our servers was migrated to 3-node cluster from a pylon server.  The connection string below is what I used previously via python and pyodbc and never had any issues.

```
server = 'test_server' 
database = 'test_db'
cnxn = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection=yes'
```

With the new server I started receiving time out errors. So i thought I had to add `MultiSubnetFailover` to the connection string such as the following

```
server = 'test_server' 
database = 'test_db'
cnxn = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection=yes;MultiSubnetFailover=True'
```

However, I am still receiving a time out error as well as an additiaonl error seen below

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)
```

Does pyodbc support MultiSubnetFailover? I couldn't find documentation one way or another.

If so, how do I implement it?  On the other side, if it does not, how would i go about connecting?

Lastly, should I use the IP address instead?

Comment: it work for me but with MultiSubnetFailover=yes  not with True

Answer (score 0):

The ancient SQL Server ODBC driver that ships with Windows doesn't support `MultiSubnetFailover`. I suggest you move to a modern driver or have your DBA set `RegisterAllProvidersIP` to zero to support down level clients.

In the interim, you could specify the current listener IP address or the host name of the current primary node. However, that will fail if the primary is failed over to a secondary node on a different subnet.